# Using CMake's include_directories command with white spaces

Tags: cmake, llvm

I am using CMake to build my project and I have the following line:

```
include_directories(${LLVM_INCLUDE_DIRS})
```

which, after evaluating `LLVM_INCLUDE_DIRS`, evaluates to:

```
include_directories(C:\Program Files\LLVM\include)
```

The problem is that this is being considered two include directories, "C:\Program" and "Files\LLVM\include".

Any idea how can I solve this problem? I tried using quotation marks, but it didn't work.

**EDIT:** It turned out that the problem is in the file `llvm-3.0\share\llvm\cmake\LLVMConfig.cmake`. I enclosed the following paths with quotation marks and the problem was solved:

```
set(LLVM_INSTALL_PREFIX C:/Program Files/LLVM)
set(LLVM_INCLUDE_DIRS ${LLVM_INSTALL_PREFIX}/include)
set(LLVM_LIBRARY_DIRS ${LLVM_INSTALL_PREFIX}/lib)
```

Comment: I am using CMake GUI. Is that what you asked for?

Comment: Somewhat. On first run when you clicked "Generate" CMake asked you which generator would you use. I suppose, it's Visual Studio?

Comment: Oh, yes, I used Visual Studio. I had the problem with Visual Studio only because of the space in "Program Files".

Comment: Just now I had a very similar problem with white spaces and CMake. Anyways, I'm a bit confused: Which is the accepted answer? The one you gave at the bottom of the OP or the one that you actually accepted? I think it would be best to post solutions as answers, not in as part of the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is more likely to be an error at the point where `LLVM_INCLUDE_DIRS` is set rather than a problem with `include_directories`.

To check this, try calling `include_directories("C:\\Program Files\\LLVM\\include")` - it should work correctly.

The problem seems to be that `LLVM_INCLUDE_DIRS` was constructed without using quotation marks.  Try for example running this:

```
set(LLVM_INCLUDE_DIRS C:\\Program Files\\LLVM\\include)
message("${LLVM_INCLUDE_DIRS}")
set(LLVM_INCLUDE_DIRS "C:\\Program Files\\LLVM\\include")
message("${LLVM_INCLUDE_DIRS}")
```

The output is:

```
C:\Program;Files\LLVM\include
C:\Program Files\LLVM\include
```

Note the semi-colon in the first output line.  This is a list with 2 items.

So the way to fix this is to modify the way in which `LLVM_INCLUDE_DIRS` is created.

Comment: Thanks for the solution. The problem was actually in the file LLVMConfig.cmake provided by LLVM. I put the paths in quotation marks and it worked :-)

Answer (score 6):

In CMake,

- whitespace is a list separator (like `;`),
- evaluating variable names basically replaces the variable name with its content and
- `\` is an escape character (to get the symbol, it needs to be escaped as well)

So, in your example, `include_directories(C:\\Pogram Files\\LLVM\\include)` is the same as

```
include_directories( C:\\Program;Files\\LLVM\\include)
```

that is, a list with two items. To avoid this, either

- escape the whitespace as well:

  `include_directories( C:\\Program\ Files\\LLVM\\include)` or
- surround the path with quotation marks:

  `include_directories( "C:\\Program Files\\LLVM\\include")`

Obviously, the second option is the better choice as it is

- simpler and easier to read and
- can be used with variable evaluation like in your example (since the result of the evaluation is then surrounded by quotation  marks and thus, treated a single item)

  include_directories("${LLVM_INCLUDE_DIRS}")

This works as well, if `LLVM_INCLUDE_DIRS` is a list of multiple directories because the items in this list will then be explicitly separated by `;` so that there is no need for unquoted whitespace as implicit list item separator.

*Side note:* 
When using hard-coded path-names (for whatever reason) in my CMake files, I usually uses forward slashes as directory separators as this works on Windows as well and avoids the need to escape all backslashes.

Comment: You still need to escape the backslashes in your second option.