# When I build and compile my c++ project it is not finding the correct c++ library via my cmake files, what am I doing wrong?

Tags: c++, cmake

When I compile my project for the following legacy library:
https://github.com/reedhedges/AriaCoda

I get the error that Aria.h is not found.

**My CMakeLists.txt:**

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.14)
project(CLion)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)

add_executable(CLion
        forward.cpp
        forward.h
        main.cpp
        )

list(APPEND CMAKE_MODULE_PATH ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/cmake)


find_package(ARIA)

target_include_directories(CLion PUBLIC ${ARIA_INCLUDE_DIRS})

target_link_libraries(CLion PUBLIC ${ARIA_LIBRARIES})
```

**My FindARIA.cmake file:**

```
#############################################################################
#
# ViSP, open source Visual Servoing Platform software.
# Copyright (C) 2005 - 2019 by Inria. All rights reserved.
#
# This software is free software; you can redistribute it and/or modify
# it under the terms of the GNU General Public License as published by
# the Free Software Foundation; either version 2 of the License, or
# (at your option) any later version.
# See the file LICENSE.txt at the root directory of this source
# distribution for additional information about the GNU GPL.
#
# For using ViSP with software that can not be combined with the GNU
# GPL, please contact Inria about acquiring a ViSP Professional
# Edition License.
#
# See http://visp.inria.fr for more information.
#
# This software was developed at:
# Inria Rennes - Bretagne Atlantique
# Campus Universitaire de Beaulieu
# 35042 Rennes Cedex
# France
#
# If you have questions regarding the use of this file, please contact
# Inria at visp@inria.fr
#
# This file is provided AS IS with NO WARRANTY OF ANY KIND, INCLUDING THE
# WARRANTY OF DESIGN, MERCHANTABILITY AND FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
#
# Description:
# Try to find Aria libraries and headers to control Pioneer mobile robots.
# Once run this will define:
#
# ARIA_FOUND
# ARIA_INCLUDE_DIRS
# ARIA_LIBRARIES
#
# Authors:
# Fabien Spindler
#
#############################################################################

find_path(ARIA_INCLUDE_DIR Aria.h
        $ENV{ARIA_HOME}/include
        /usr/local/Aria/include
        /usr/Aria/include
        /usr/include
        /usr/include/Aria
        /usr/local/include
        /usr/local/include/Aria
        "C:/Program Files/MobileRobots/Aria/include"
        )
#MESSAGE("DBG ARIA_INCLUDE_DIR=${ARIA_INCLUDE_DIR}")

if(UNIX)
    find_library(ARIA_LIBRARY
            NAMES Aria
            PATHS
            $ENV{ARIA_HOME}/lib
            /usr/local/Aria/lib
            /usr/Aria/lib
            /usr/lib
            /usr/local/lib
            )
    #MESSAGE("DBG ARIA_LIBRARY=${ARIA_LIBRARY}")
else()
    if(MSVC14)
        set(ARIA_SUFFIX_NAME VC14)
    elseif(MSVC12)
        set(ARIA_SUFFIX_NAME VC12)
    elseif(MSVC11)
        set(ARIA_SUFFIX_NAME VC11)
    elseif(MSVC10)
        set(ARIA_SUFFIX_NAME VC10)
    elseif(MSVC90)
        set(ARIA_SUFFIX_NAME VC9)
    elseif(MSVC80)
        set(ARIA_SUFFIX_NAME VC8)
    elseif(MSVC71)
        set(ARIA_SUFFIX_NAME VC71)
    else()
        set(ARIA_SUFFIX_NAME "")
    endif()

    set(ARIA_LIB_SEARCH_PATH "")
    if(CMAKE_CL_64)
        list(APPEND ARIA_LIB_SEARCH_PATH "C:/Program Files/MobileRobots/Aria/lib64")
        list(APPEND ARIA_LIB_SEARCH_PATH $ENV{ARIA_HOME}/lib64)
    else()
        list(APPEND ARIA_LIB_SEARCH_PATH "C:/Program Files/MobileRobots/Aria/lib")
        list(APPEND ARIA_LIB_SEARCH_PATH $ENV{ARIA_HOME}/lib)
    endif()

    find_library(ARIA_LIBRARY_DEBUG
            NAMES AriaDebug${ARIA_SUFFIX_NAME}
            PATHS
            ${ARIA_LIB_SEARCH_PATH}
            )
    find_library(ARIA_LIBRARY_RELEASE
            NAMES Aria${ARIA_SUFFIX_NAME}
            PATHS
            ${ARIA_LIB_SEARCH_PATH}
            )
endif()

if(UNIX)
    if(ARIA_LIBRARY AND ARIA_INCLUDE_DIR)
        set(ARIA_INCLUDE_DIRS ${ARIA_INCLUDE_DIR})
        set(ARIA_LIBRARIES ${ARIA_LIBRARY})
        set(ARIA_FOUND TRUE)
    else()
        set(ARIA_FOUND FALSE)
    endif()
else()
    set(ARIA_LIBRARIES "")
    if(ARIA_LIBRARY_RELEASE AND ARIA_INCLUDE_DIR)
        set(ARIA_INCLUDE_DIRS ${ARIA_INCLUDE_DIR})
        list(APPEND ARIA_LIBRARIES optimized ${ARIA_LIBRARY_RELEASE})
        set(ARIA_FOUND TRUE)
    endif()
    IF(ARIA_LIBRARY_DEBUG AND ARIA_INCLUDE_DIR)
        set(ARIA_INCLUDE_DIRS ${ARIA_INCLUDE_DIR})
        list(APPEND ARIA_LIBRARIES debug ${ARIA_LIBRARY_DEBUG})
        set(ARIA_FOUND TRUE)
    endif()

endif()

mark_as_advanced(
        ARIA_INCLUDE_DIR
        ARIA_LIBRARY
        ARIA_LIBRARY_DEBUG
        ARIA_LIBRARY_RELEASE
        ARIA_LIB_SEARCH_PATH
)
```

What am I doing incorrectly and how can I fix or at least improve both my CMAKE files (I am still learning CMAKE)?

Currently using the IDE Clion in Windows 10 with GCC compiler.

Most relevant directories to find the c++ library installed on this system:

```
C:\Program Files\MobileRobots\Aria
C:\Program Files\MobileRobots\Aria\include
C:\Program Files\MobileRobots\Aria\bin64
C:\Program Files\MobileRobots\Aria\lib64
```

I have noticed as well in the find file (which I got from github) does not have the directory `C:\Program Files\MobileRobots\Aria\bin64` which I believe to be relevant but can't work out how to add it into the cmake file.

Comment: In `CMakeLists.txt` you use `ARIA_INCLUDE_DIRS` variable, which should contain ARIA include directory. Start with printing the value of this variable (after `find_package(ARIA)` call) and check that the directory, contained in the variable, actually has given header file. If it doesn't, then something wrong with your `FindARIA.cmake` script. Uncomment `MESSAGE` lines in it, and try to debug.

Comment: Printing the directory for `ARIA_INCLUDE_DIRS` outputs: `DBG ARIA_INCLUDE_DIR=C:/Program Files/MobileRobots/Aria/include` the directory definitely exists in windows 10. the only difference being here is in Windows for a directory you have `\` instead of `/` but I find CMAKE classes `\` as invalid syntax, thus presuming this is corrected somehow on compilation of the cmake file? Other than that I have been at this a couple of hours, and whatever I add or do seems to make it worse.

Comment: You are printing `ARIA_INCLUDE_DIR`, but `CMakeLists.txt` uses `ARIA_INCLUDE_DIRS` one (with ending `S`). While your `FindIRIA.cmake` script assigned value of variable `ARIA_INCLUDE_DIR` to variable `ARIA_INCLUDE_DIRS` in every branch, it is possible that none of that branches is executed. So please, print value **exactly** for variable `ARIA_INCLUDE_DIRS`.

Comment: I tried this, thanks, in reference to below answer as well it has allowed for some progress on this issue but not a complete solution as of yet.

Comment: It would be beneficial to show the build output when compiling the file that generates the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that `Aria.h` exists in `C:/Program Files/MobileRobots/Aria/include` you might need to quote for the spaces.  [Using CMake's include_directories command with white spaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9964775/using-cmakes-include-directories-command-with-white-spaces)

I'd confirm that the `-I` directive on the command line is correct.

Try:

```
target_include_directories(CLion PUBLIC "${ARIA_INCLUDE_DIRS}")
target_link_libraries(CLion PUBLIC "${ARIA_LIBRARIES}")
```

Comment: Ah thanks, I think this has made it find the library so thanks for that. Not sure what you mean by `-I` how would I type this in the command line exactly for example? Additionally, how would I include C:\Program Files\MobileRobots\Aria\bin64 into my CMAKE find file or cmake lists file? I think it is looking for this directory now or its looking for a .dll file which is in my main project directory. Aria.h does exist in the directory you mentioned.

Comment: @SomeT You don't say which generator you are using.  But it being windows I guess you are using Visual Studio.  When you build the project in a shell using something like `cmake --build .` it will build the software showing all the commands being issued by `msbuild.exe`.  Part of that is compiling the source code and it will show the command line being used.  The `-I` compiler option is used to set additional search directories.  You need to verify that the expected directory is correctly being used.

Comment: Yeah I believe in the find file I posted in my initial question it says MSVC14 which appropriates somehow but CLion is definitely using a seperate GCC installation I have, the CMAKE is included with CLion so I am not sure how to do it in CLion I will research. I think if you are saying there is no more appropiate things to fix in my files now then I will mark your answer as most correct. I should hopefully be able to work it out from here, but I believe a more direct new question may be viable on superuser if I am still struggling with CMake dynamics or CLion support.

Comment: Actually I tried these commands, it don't work, specifically `Error: could not load cache` and I am not sure if when I am typing on the terminal its using the cmake I have installed at system level or the one installed with CLion?

Comment: @SomeT I'm not familiar with CLion and how it uses CMake.  That can complicate things because it looks like it calls CMake for you using settings based on a list of toolchains it provides.  The `Error: could not load cache` error happens when `cmake --build .` is run in a directory that is not a CMake build directory.  The CMake build directory will contain a file called `CMakeCache.txt`.

Comment: Yes, my project directory in folder `cmake-build-debug` has the file `CMakeCache.txt` also out put of such file is here: https://hastebin.com/raw/yasifenesa

Comment: When I got that error actually I think it was more cmake on the system level not so much on the project level, I can't work out if CLion has a form of terminal input for CMake for the bundled version.